# Individually output carry flags. MASM Assembly

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I called the `lahf` operand and move the value from `ah` to a variable of type byte that I named `eFlagContents`. I know how to output the carry flags all together like this.

```
MOVZX EAX, eFlagContents
MOV EBX, LENGTHOF eFlagContents
CALL WriteBinB
CALL Crlf
```

But how would I output each flag individually?

Comment: By saving EFLAGS somewhere and then looping over the bits, e.g. with a right shift.  How do you think WriteBinB is implemented?  (Note that OF isn't part of what `lahf` saves, so you'll want `pushf`)

Comment: how would you cycle through the bits all i have been able to output the entire byte for eFlags but i dont know how to each bit to print.